# Jquery Accordion adding replacement attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to change the font size for the title section of the accordion located here `body {
  font: 16px Sans-Serif;

}`

Unfortunately, i already have a "body" attribute which overrides the above code within my site.

How can i replace the above attribute and replace it with another attribute name that will correspond to the change in font size for the title. For example, instead of "body", how about "title_size".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Jquery Accordion here: http://jsfiddle.net/q2Gm9/

Comment: To mess with only your accordion title, just do this .accordion dt {} though I am not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css and it will work:

```
.accordion dt{font: 16px sans-serif;}
```

Comment: Small sidenote: `sans-serif` should be in lowercase (even though it isn't in the question either).

Comment: it looks like it was indeed what i thought you were asking - glad I could help! :)